# Propagate / broadcast a value in groups back to the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as following:

```
Year-Week   Ticket  Policy       User
2022-35     12502   COMPLIED      MX 
2022-35     12502   NOT COMPLIED  US
2022-35     12502   COMPLIED      AL
2022-35     12502   COMPLIED      BR
2022-35     12471   COMPLIED      DE
2022-35     12409   COMPLIED      US
2022-35     12409   NOT COMPLIED  BR
2022-35     12406   COMPLIED      MX
```

When there are duplicate tickets, how could I standardize that each ticket has the same policy? E.g: If a ticket in a week has "NOT COMPLIED", the policy should be the same for that ticket no matter the week, so, should be something like this:

**Output Sample**

```
Year-Week   Ticket  Policy       User
2022-35     12502   NOT COMPLIED  MX 
2022-35     12502   NOT COMPLIED  US
2022-35     12502   NOT COMPLIED  AL
2022-35     12502   NOT COMPLIED  BR
2022-35     12471   COMPLIED      DE
2022-35     12409   NOT COMPLIED  US
2022-35     12409   NOT COMPLIED  BR
2022-35     12406   COMPLIED      MX
```

Basically what I want is the dominance of NOT COMPLIED over COMPLIED when there are duplicated Tickets.

Comment: what if for duplicated ticket within a week, it says COMPILED... ?

Answer (score 1):

Leverage the fact that `"N"` comes after `"C"` on the ASCII table. So `max()` would take "NOT COMPLIED" over "COMPLIED".

As you want to propagate the same policy for each Ticket, call `max()` using `groupby().transform()` so that the result is indexed the same as the original dataframe, allowing you to directly assign the result back to the dataframe.

```py
df['Policy'] = df.groupby('Ticket')['Policy'].transform('max')
```

```
  Year-Week  Ticket        Policy User
0   2022-35   12502  NOT COMPLIED   MX
1   2022-35   12502  NOT COMPLIED   US
2   2022-35   12502  NOT COMPLIED   AL
3   2022-35   12502  NOT COMPLIED   BR
4   2022-35   12471      COMPLIED   DE
5   2022-35   12409  NOT COMPLIED   US
6   2022-35   12409  NOT COMPLIED   BR
7   2022-35   12406      COMPLIED   MX
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked! But I've a question, what would I do if the order of the ASCII table is not followed? I mean, instead of having COMPLIED and NOT COMPLIED, I have a different set of words?

Comment: @exenlediatán you can use `df['Policy'] = np.where(df['Policy'].eq('NOT COMPLIED').groupby(df['Ticket']).transform('max'), 'NOT COMPLIED', 'COMPLIED')` for the general case (where you can change NOT COMPLIED and COMPLIED into any value you want).

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code;

```
df1 = df[['Year-Week', 'Ticket']].drop_duplicates()

policy = []
for time,ticket in zip(df1['Year-Week'],df1['Ticket']):
    df_temp = df[(df["Year-Week"] == time) & (df["Ticket"] == ticket)]
    if "NOT COMPLIED" in df_temp["Policy"].to_list():
        policy.extend(["NOT COMPLIED"] * df_temp.shape[0])
    else:
        policy.extend(["COMPLIED"] * df_temp.shape[0])
        
df["Policy"] = policy
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I think this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do a groupby followed by a transfrom and set it to the Policy column;

```
df['Policy'] = df.groupby(['Year-Week','Ticket']).Policy.transform(lambda x: 'NOT COMPLIED'if 'NOT COMPLIED' in x else 'COMPLIED')
```

Comment: I've tried this form and it keeps showing the following error: "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"